# Operation not possible due to RF-Kill

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I think I've looked at any other thread that asks this question - I am stuck with this problem for quite a while.

When I boot my system (Kali Linux Rolling) there is an error in `Raise Network Interface [Failed]` and `systemctl status networking.service` outputs:

```
# systemctl status networking.service 
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor prese
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-10-25 09:24:36 IDT; 6min ag
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
 Main PID: 616 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 25 09:24:35 MY-PC systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Oct 25 09:24:36 MY-PC ifup[616]: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible 
Oct 25 09:24:36 MY-PC ifup[616]: Failed to bring up wlan0.
Oct 25 09:24:36 MY-PC systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, 
Oct 25 09:24:36 MY-PC systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Oct 25 09:24:36 MY-PC systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed s
Oct 25 09:24:36 MY-PC systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'e
```

My network card is `Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)`. My network card is new yet I can't see any networks showing (it once worked but somehow, now it doesn't) when there clearly are networks around.

Here are some outputs of commands that will spill some useful information on the scenario:

```
# iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

# rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no [COMMENT: THIS IS SOFT BLOCKED WHEN WIFI IS OFF AND IS NOT WHEN I TURN ON WIFI]
    Hard blocked: no
```

I am having this problem for quite a while, any way to fix this and have my WiFi working again?

Comment: Cf https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399577/rtnetlink-answers-operation-not-possible-due-to-rf-kill-on-hp-pavilon-dv8000