# "RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill" on HP Pavilon dv8000

Tags: linux, debian, networking, network-interface

I'm running Debian 9 on HP Pavilion dv8000 with an Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG card inside.

When I turn on the system `ip addr` shows that the related `wlp6s0` interface is down.

However, when I try to bring it up using `ip link set wlp6s0 up` I get the following error:

> RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill

I don't have `rfkill` installed, so I cannot use it to diagnose/fix it.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the black WiFi button above the keyboard. It enables and disables WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

On Manjaro, I had turned off the wifi from the settings. Settings can be accessed by right clicking on the wifi symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue as the OP.

After turning Wi-Fi on, despite being hardwired, I noticed wlp0 was back up and I was able to run `sudo dhclient -r` `sudo dhclient` again.